# nodejs console.log of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I'm printing the error object in nodejs. The output of console.log(err) looks like:

```
{ [error: column "pkvalue" does not exist]
  name: 'error',
  length: 96,
  severity: 'ERROR'}
```

What is the information printed in square  brackets and how to access it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just common `Error` part
Rest is additional defined fields:

```
$ node
> var e = new Error('Some error');
undefined
> e.field = 'value'
'value'
> console.log(e)
{ [Error: Some error] field: 'value' }
```

You can access to error message as `message` field:

```
> e.message
'Some error'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the message is not visible as normal property when you print the error object. What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: I think it just custom `toString` method implementation for `Error`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `util.inspect` instead, it gives more verbose information and serialize objects to strings differently.

See https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: Hi I've tried but util.inspect prints it exactly the same way. @vp_arth answer is what I wanted